# OR operator applying to entire WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
customers.customer_id,
services.name
FROM users
INNER JOIN customers ON users.user_id=customers.user_id
LEFT JOIN appointments ON customers.customer_id=appointments.customer_id
INNER JOIN pets ON customers.customer_id=pets.customer_id
INNER JOIN services on appointments.service_id=services.service_id
WHERE ((appointments.customer_id IS NULL) 
    OR NOT (appointments.date > (SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 365)))
    OR ((appointments.date > (SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 365))) 
         AND services.name NOT LIKE '%General Health Checkup%'))
GROUP BY customers.customer_id
```

I am trying to find all customers who are due a yearly general health checkup
this requires them to have:
a) never have appointments
b) not had an appointment in the past year
c) had an appointment in the past year but it wasn't a general health checkup

I assumed the final OR im my WHERE clause would only apply to that that operation i.e.

```
OR ((appointments.date > (SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 365))) AND services.name NOT LIKE '%General Health Checkup%'))
```

however it is ruling out all options for services named General Health Checkup.

[image: Query result]

How can i only apply this to that area of the where clause so that general health check up appointments can get through but only if they are from over a year ago.

Thanks !

appointments table:

```
CREATE TABLE `appointments` (
  `appointment_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pet_id` int(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Open','Cancelled','Completed','') NOT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `appointments`
--

INSERT INTO `appointments` (`appointment_id`, `customer_id`, `service_id`, `staff_id`, `pet_id`, `date`, `start_time`, `status`, `create_date`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, '2017-03-22', '10:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-16 11:28:46'),
(2, 3, 2, 1, 6, '2021-06-18', '12:00:00', 'Completed', '2021-06-15 11:01:43'),
(3, 2, 2, 1, 2, '2020-07-17', '13:00:00', 'Completed', '2020-05-14 11:30:18'),
(4, 3, 2, 1, 5, '2020-07-10', '14:00:00', 'Completed', '2020-05-21 11:30:18'),
(5, 4, 3, 1, 7, '2020-09-17', '10:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-16 12:31:59'),
(6, 8, 2, 1, 11, '2022-03-17', '12:00:00', 'Cancelled', '2022-03-17 23:44:56'),
(7, 4, 2, 7, 7, '2022-03-17', '10:00:00', 'Cancelled', '2022-03-17 23:50:11'),
(8, 1, 1, 13, 1, '2022-03-17', '13:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-18 00:28:10'),
(9, 7, 2, 13, 9, '2022-03-18', '15:00:00', 'Cancelled', '2022-03-18 13:16:37'),
(10, 7, 1, 13, 10, '2022-03-18', '16:00:00', 'Cancelled', '2022-03-18 13:48:12'),
(11, 1, 1, 13, 1, '2022-03-22', '11:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-22 12:34:55'),
(12, 11, 1, 13, 11, '2022-03-23', '13:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-23 15:28:22'),
(13, 9, 3, 13, 12, '2022-03-26', '13:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-26 13:13:46'),
(14, 35, 2, 13, 16, '2022-03-27', '10:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-27 16:09:14'),
(15, 34, 2, 13, 20, '2022-03-28', '10:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-28 10:05:41'),
(16, 33, 1, 13, 20, '2022-03-28', '12:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-28 11:40:50'),
(17, 8, 2, 13, 20, '2022-03-16', '14:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-28 12:31:42'),
(18, 15, 2, 13, 20, '2022-03-28', '14:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-28 12:33:47'),
(19, 31, 4, 13, 20, '2022-03-29', '00:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-29 14:20:04'),
(20, 31, 4, 13, 20, '2022-03-29', '10:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-29 14:20:42'),
(21, 1, 1, 13, 1, '2022-03-30', '11:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-30 15:18:23'),
(22, 33, 4, 13, 22, '2022-03-30', '12:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-30 15:22:02'),
(23, 3, 1, 13, 5, '2022-03-30', '13:00:00', 'Open', '2022-03-30 15:22:02'),
(24, 4, 1, 13, 7, '2022-03-30', '13:30:00', 'Completed', '2022-03-30 15:24:52'),
(25, 7, 2, 13, 10, '2022-03-30', '14:30:00', 'Open', '2022-03-30 15:26:11'),
(26, 12, 1, 7, 8, '2022-04-21', '10:00:00', 'Open', '2022-04-21 12:54:10'),
(27, 2, 1, 1, 8, '2022-04-21', '10:00:00', 'Cancelled', '2022-04-21 13:16:23'),
(28, 17, 4, 1, 20, '2022-04-21', '10:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-04-21 13:18:41'),
(29, NULL, 6, 7, 21, '2022-04-21', '12:00:00', 'Completed', '2022-04-21 16:22:44'),
(30, 13, 2, 3, 5, '2022-04-21', '14:00:00', 'Open', '2022-04-21 17:42:10'),
(31, 5, 1, 9, 14, '2022-04-22', '11:00:00', 'Open', '2022-04-22 16:16:57');
```

services table:

```
CREATE TABLE `services` (
  `service_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `average_time` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `services`
--

INSERT INTO `services` (`service_id`, `name`, `description`, `average_time`) VALUES
(1, 'Consultation', 'General consultation to help you find the best path to good health for your pet.', 30),
(2, 'General Health Checkup', 'Review of your pets health.', 30),
(3, 'Microchip Insertion', 'Keep your dog safe and trackable with microchip.', 90),
(4, 'Puppy Vaccination', 'Initial puppy vaccination', 30),
(6, 'Booster Vaccination', 'Regular booster vaccincation service.', 30);
```

Comment: Add more parentheses?

Comment: Why invoke users and pets when you don't use them in select? select in SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 365 is unnecessary ,there's way to many brackets, and if it was me I would test last date rather all dates in last year test and if any in last year was general..and what on earth does services name in select mean if there has never been an appointment? sample data and desired outcome as text would help.

Comment: @P.Salmon I removed certain columns i selected to reduce the complexity of the query  for stackoverflow but forgot to remove the joins. How do you mean last test date? What data would be helpful ? the services and appointments table?

Comment: the services and appointments table? - yes a representative sample with table definitions.

Comment: Hope this is sufficient

Comment: Given there aren't any where the most recent appoinment is more than a year ago the sample is not representative, and how is there an appointment with customer_id of null?

Answer (score 0):

I would just check if the customer had a service_id=2 in the last year:

```
SELECT  
   customers.customer_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(services.name,'(',appointments.date,')')) as services
FROM users
INNER JOIN customers ON users.user_id=customers.user_id
LEFT JOIN appointments ON customers.customer_id=appointments.customer_id
INNER JOIN pets ON customers.customer_id=pets.customer_id
INNER JOIN services on appointments.service_id=services.service_id
WHERE SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 365) > (SELECT MAX(date)
                 FROM appointments 
                 WHERE customers.customer_id=appointments.customer_id
                   AND appointments.service_id=2)
GROUP BY customers.customer_id
```

output:

| customer_id | services |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | General Health Checkup(2017-03-22),Consultation(2022-03-30),Consultation(2022-03-22),Consultation(2022-03-17) |
| 2 | General Health Checkup(2020-07-17),Consultation(2022-04-21) |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=15108e94518d4aee49c252bbe410d101)